# Eclipse error code 1 in Windows10

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded scala ide for eclipse into my windows 10 system which is 64 bit one.

If I try to open eclipse then is throwing error code 1 saying java was started but returned error code 1.

I gave java path in environment variable and added the java path into eclipse.ini as below but still throwing the same error.

## eclipse.ini code:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-
1133
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xmx2G
-Xms200m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 64 bit requires Java 64 bit.

On 64-bit Windows you can either use:

- your current 64-bit Eclipse IDE with a 64-bit Java VM or
- a 32-bit Eclipse IDE with your current 32-bit Java VM.

See also [Eclipse Wiki: eclipse.ini - Specifying the JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)

Answer (score 0):

Is your Eclipse version a 64 bit one? If so you should have Java Development Kit 64 bit. If you have 32bit Eclipse, then you need 32bit version of Java Development Kit. And if you get the same error after installing the proper versions of the Eclipse and JDK, you should go to Eclipse ‘s directory (eg: C:\ProgramFiles\Eclipse\ for 64bit) and edit the eclipse.ini file by adding the following lines after “—launcher.appendVmargs” and before -vmargs;

> -vm
>
> C:\ProgramFiles\Java\javaJdkversion that you have\bin\javaw.exe

save this and launch eclipse.